# Get full fields in nested model. Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 model classes:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    tags = models.ManyToManyField('events.Tag', related_name='user_tag', blank=True)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
```

And serializers:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
         ...

class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        lookup_field = 'name'
        model = Tag
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

When I do a get query I get something like this:

```
 "data": {
    "type": "CustomUser",
    "id": "6",
    "attributes": {
        "username": "mercer",
    },
    "relationships": {
        "tags": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "type": "Tag",
                    "id": "1"
                }
            ]
        },

    }
}
```

What I want is to get Tag 'name' field in user representation:

```
"type": "Tag",
"id": "1",
"name":"name"
```

And I want to make patch query for adding tag to user.

I can use `SerializerMethodField()`, but this way I will not able to add tags

Comment: This json does not seem to be the output of given code.

Comment: It's not full output, only a part

Comment: I agree with @Ivan Starostin, that json that you put as the response from the serializer doesn't look like what you usually get from a serializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with settings of rest framework. I wrote there custom json render classes and recived this form of output. Now i removed it and everything is fine.